# Variables with variable names in C#

Tags: c#, php

In php you can create variables with variable names using `${'variable'.$count}`

but at the moment I need this in C#, is there a C# equivalent for this?

EDIT:

Basically what im trying to do is create a timer every time the space bar is pressed,
the first time the name is timer1 second time timer2..

Comment: After your Edit: I would still go for a Dicitonary because that's the way to keep track of values by keys. (Dictionary also ensures there are no duplicate keys). However I Would change the type for the value from object to Timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the values in a `Dictionary` in C#. That way you could retrieve a value according to a specific key.

```
IDictionary<string, object> variables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Add a variable:

```
variables.Add("varname", 11);
```

Then to retrieve te variables you can use:

```
var myVar = variables.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "varname");
```

Note to include `using System.Linq;` to use `.SingleOrDefault()`

Because the `object` type is used as a value, all kinds of variables can be stored; (int, string, custom class instances). but note that you'll have to cast the variable back to your type when using it

**EDIT:** If you only use Timers, use this dictionary declaration:

```
IDictionary<string, Timer> variables = new Dicitonary<string, Timer>();
```

Comment: Using Dictionary is a good way! +1

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Can I use a variable instead of 11?

Comment: @Wim 11 is an int variable. You can use any variable you want. Also a Timer as your edit reveils. But if the collection will only contain timers, i suggest changing the object Type of the dictionary to Timer. In that way you won't need to cast the value back after retrieving it

Answer (score 1):

Then create your own Timer type, where you encapsulate the logic of updating the name. No need for variable variables.

```
class MyTimer
{
 // ...

 public void Increment()
 {
   this.name = "name" + (count++).ToString();
 }

 private string name;
 private int cout;
}
```